# System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(string strVar) Doesn't work properly

Tags: c#

I am getting error message when i tried to update database table with content of richtext document (TinyMCE editor)  in c#

The error message : `Error in UpdateListing : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@short_description,listing_content='<h3 dir="ltr">$50-100 in mon' at line 1`

This is what happening at the button click

```
protected void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

            W2Travellers.Libs.CommonClass objCC = new Libs.CommonClass();
            W2Travellers.Libs.AddListingResult objLR = new Libs.AddListingResult();
            W2Travellers.Libs.ListingData objLD = new Libs.ListingData();
            objLD.strListingId = Request.QueryString["listing_id"].ToString().Trim();
            objLD.strListingType = ddlUserType.SelectedItem.Value;
            objLD.strListingTypeText = ddlUserType.SelectedItem.Text;
            objLD.strTargetGroup = ddlTargetGroup.SelectedItem.Value;
            objLD.strTargetGroupText = ddlTargetGroup.SelectedItem.Text;
            objLD.strDisplayName = txtListingTitle.Text.ToString().Trim();
            objLD.strListingTags = txtListingTags.Text.ToString().Trim();
            objLD.strShortDes = txtShortDescription.Text.ToString().Trim();
            string strLC = txtListingBody.Text.ToString().Trim();
            objLD.strListingContent = System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(strLC);
            //objLD.strListingContent = txtListingBody.Text.ToString().Trim();

            W2Travellers.Libs.Listing objListing = new Libs.Listing();
            objLR = objListing.UpdateListing(objLD);
            if (objLR.boolAddListingResult == true)
            {
                lblInnerMsg.Text = objLR.strMsg;
            }
            else
            {
                lblInnerMsg.Text = objLR.strMsg;
            }

    }
```

**This is the function in the class file**

```
public AddListingResult UpdateListing(ListingData objListingData)
    {
        AddListingResult objLR = new AddListingResult();
        MySqlCommand objComUpdate = new MySqlCommand();
        MySqlConnection objCon = new MySqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MySQLConnStr"].ConnectionString);
        try
        {
            objCon.Open();
            objComUpdate = objCon.CreateCommand();
            objComUpdate.CommandText = "Update listing_meta set listing_type=@listing_type,listing_type_text=@listing_type_text,target_group=@target_group,target_group_text=@target_group_text,display_name_listing=@display_name_listing,tags=@tags,short_description@short_description,listing_content=@listing_content where listing_id=@listing_id";
            objComUpdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@listing_id", objListingData.strListingId);
            objComUpdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@listing_type", objListingData.strListingType);
            objComUpdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@listing_type_text", objListingData.strListingTypeText);
            objComUpdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@target_group", objListingData.strTargetGroup);
            objComUpdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@target_group_text", objListingData.strTargetGroupText);
            objComUpdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@display_name_listing", objListingData.strDisplayName);
            objComUpdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tags", objListingData.strListingTags);
            objComUpdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@short_description", objListingData.strShortDes);
            objComUpdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@listing_content", objListingData.strListingContent);                
            objComUpdate.ExecuteNonQuery();
            objLR.boolAddListingResult = true;
            objLR.strMsg = "Draft Updated!";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            objLR.boolAddListingResult = false;
            objLR.strMsg = "Error in UpdateListing : " + ex.Message;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (objCon.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                objCon.Close();
            }
        }
        return objLR;
    }
```

Comment: You probably meant `short_description=@short_description` (beware the `=`)?

Answer (score 1):

Take care of this in the query, it's wrong

short_description@short_description

Should be

short_description = @short_description

Comment: What for?  Maybe you can set my answer as  approved :-)